# Why can't I define an array size using #define constant?

Tags: c, arrays, c-preprocessor

#### Method 1: works

```
const int MAX_STRING = 256;

int main(void) {
    char buffer[MAX_STRING];
}
```

#### Method 2: Does not work - compilation error.

```
#define MAX_STRING 256;

int main(void) {
    char buffer[MAX_STRING];
}
```

What is the reason of the different behavior of those codes? Are those both `MAX_STRING`s not constants?